# angularjs - directive - two way binding, getting keys from collection in the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a picker dialog as a directive, the input is a collection of json data. I am then trying in the template to use a table in which the collection keys are in the thead. The thing is, the collection data is displaying ok (currently displaying in the template just 'name' property), the i cant get the keys, because $scope.collection returns undefined. Using Lo-Dash to get the keys.

I have a directive:

```
.directive('pb5pickerDialog', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{
            collection : '=',
            onsubmit : '&'
        },
        templateUrl: "/pb5/c/js/views/pb5pickerDialog.html",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.onclose = function(){
             $("#pb5pickerDialog").modal('toggle');
          };
          console.log(scope.collection); //this undefined
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element){
           console.log($scope.collection); //this undefined
           console.log(_.keys($scope.collection));
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because `$scope.collection` is set after your linking function is called. You should probably set up a watch on it and take action when you get the initial value. Something like:

```
controller: function($scope, $element){
  $scope.$watch('collection', function(collection, oldValue) {
    if (collection) {
      // collection is now set
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Great! Do note that the watch will fire every time the `collection` property on the scope is set, so don't place any code in the watch that should only be called once unless you check that.